# Automatically mount cifs shares after login with AD user in linux machine

Tags: linux, active-directory, mount, synology, cifs

I need to mount a Synology cifs share for users who login to a Centos  machine with their AD user.
The Synology is in Domain and shares have been assigned to groups.
The Linux is in Domain and home dir is created automatically when user log in the first time.
As everything is in place since many years, I cannot change from Samba to NFS or other type of filesystem.

Example.
User John Doe, belongs to John Group, has a share SynJohn

Mary from another group has another folder.
John enters and need to access SynJohn, as it's his first time his home will be populated
according the skel directory, but I do not know in advance if he has a domain account or not, and I can't (and I do not want) to create manually an entry in /etc/fstab.

On the Synology the root folder is not shared, so I cannot mount /volumex/ and let people access /volumex/SynJohn /volumex/SynMary etc.

I've tried to give sudo permission on mount -t cifs but it seems that is not possible as
the mount points change. Using variables in /etc/fstab is not permitted.

My idea was to create a credentials file and let the user  fill it and use it to mount the share manually, or better automatically via bashrc..

I hope to have explained myself more or less...

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you that each user should only have write access to shares which they have been specifically granted access to. Thus, for this purpose, when an AD user logs in to a share which is remotely mounted on the linux system, you can use the following command and use a credentials file which contains the username, password and domain of the concerned user that is accessing the file share. Refer below the command for more information: -

```
 ‘ sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<win_share_user>,domain=<win_domain> 
   //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share ‘  -  when the user is in windows 
   AD domain
   Credentials format - username=user
                        password=password
                        domain=domain
```

•   To set the correct permissions and ownership on the credential file , run the following -

```
 ‘ $sudo chown root: /etc/win-credentials
   $sudo chmod 600 /etc/win-credentials ‘
```

To use the credentials file, define it as – ‘ sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/win-credentials //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share ‘

•   By default, if the mounted share is owned by root, and the permissions are set to 777, use the dir_mode option to set the directory permission and file_mode to set the file permission: -

```
  'sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/win- 
   credentials,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755 //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> 
   /mnt/win_share'
```

The default user and group ownership can be changed with the uid and gid options as below: -

```
 ‘ sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/etc/win- 
   credentials,uid=1000,gid=1000,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755 
     //WIN_SHARE_IP/<share_name> /mnt/win_share ‘
```

To set additional options , add them as a comma-separated list after the -o option. To get a list of all mount options type man mount in your terminal.